# What's a "delay line"?

Tags: delay

I know what a delay is, but
what's a delay **line**? 
What's the reason for calling it a "delay line"?

Comment: My guess is that it relates to the historical use of electrical or acoustic propagation time down a physical object, such as a wire "line" or pipe "line", for time delaying signals by a deterministic and known amount.

Comment: I wonder if using the term "delay line" is a bit of a misnormer in digital implementations. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_delay_line, but is there a line in the digital implementation?

Comment: $z^{-N}$ ......

Comment: hotpaw2: I agree. I once worked a commercial radio station and they had a rack-mounted device containing a stainless steel spring about 5" in length. They would apply a rotational torque to one end of the spring at audio frequencies. The vibration wave traveled down the spring and was sensed by a piezoelectric sensor at the far end. Adding the sensor output voltage to the original audio signal produced a desirable echo. They called that device "the delay line."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The term **delay line** comes from (analog) telecommunications where timing between different signals needed to be adjusted by delaying one of them. For example, [the chrominance and luminance channels in a cathode-ray-tube colour television.](http://www.hawestv.com/mtv_color%5Cdelayline.htm)

The reason it's called a **line** is because that's all it really is: a wire. The website linked to above has the following diagram of one.

[image]

In the discrete (digital) domain, I've more usually heard delay lines called [***tapped* delay lines**](http://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/pasp/Tapped_Delay_Line_TDL.html).  That's because each sample is a delay, and to form an FIR filter, we need access (to *tap* into) the signal at different delays.  The line of $z^{-1}$ boxes in the diagram below is what I would call a tapped delay line.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To substantiate hotpaw2's comment, I once worked a commercial radio station and they had a rack-mounted device containing a stainless steel spring about 5" in length. By way of electronics they would apply a back-n-forth rotational torque, at audio frequencies, to one end of the spring. The vibrating wave traveled down the spring and was sensed by a piezoelectric sensor at the far end. Adding the sensor output voltage to the original audio signal produced a desirable echo. The disc jockeys referred to that device "the delay line."